# How do I fill empty records from scraping Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36'}
r = requests.get('https://www.transfermarkt.com.br/esporte-clube-bahia/kader/verein/10010/saison_id/2019/plus/1', headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
impar = soup.find('table',{'class':'items'}).find_all('tr',{'class':'odd'})

bahia = []

for jog in impar:
    nome = jog.find_all('tr')[0].img.get('alt')
    posicao = jog.find_all('td',{'class':"zentriert"})[0].get('title')
    idade = jog.find_all('td',{'class':"zentriert"})[1].text
    nacionalidade = jog.find_all('td',{'class':"zentriert"})[2].img.get('alt')
    altura = jog.find_all('td',{'class':"zentriert"})[3].text[0:-2]
    pe = jog.find_all('td',{'class':"zentriert"})[4].text
    desde =jog.find_all('td',{'class':"zentriert"})[5].text
    clube_anterior = jog.find_all('td',{'class':'zentriert'})[6].img.get('alt')
    preco_pago = jog.find_all('td',{'class':"zentriert"})[6].get('title')
    contrato = jog.find_all('td',{'class':"zentriert"})[7].text
    valor = jog.find('td',{'class':"rechts hauptlink"}).text[0:-4]
    bahia.append((nome,posicao,idade,nacionalidade,altura,pe,desde,clube_anterior,preco_pago,contrato,valor))
```

My problem here is that some of elements of the list from where Im scraping dont have the a atribute "clube_anterior". When I try `impar[7].find_all('td',{'class':"zentriert"})[6]`, I get `<td class="zentriert"></td>` then when I do `impar[7].find_all('td',{'class':"zentriert"})[6].img.get('alt')` I get an error(
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get')`, but this code works for most of my records... Is there anyway that I can skip  the record which yields in this erros or fill then with NaN or None ?

Comment: Just to be more clear, in the other hand, when I do `impar[1].find_all('td',{'class':"zentriert"})[6]`, I get `<td class="zentriert"><a class="vereinprofil_tooltip" href="/sc-internacional-porto-alegre/startseite/verein/6600/saison_id/2018" id="6600"><img alt="SC Internacional Porto Alegre" class="" src="https://tmssl.akamaized.net/images/wappen/verysmall/6600.png?lm=1412878908" title=": Ablöse custo zero"/></a></td>`  So I do can apply `impar[1].find_all('td',{'class':"zentriert"})[6].img.get('alt')` and get no error

Comment: Please move your additional comment into the body of your Q. and consider to edit your Q so you are telling the most simpleversion of your story  (yet complete) without side discussions. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the access in `try: except AttributeError:`.

You're also re-querying the TDs over and over again for no reason; I refactored that too:

```
for jog in impar:
    nome = jog.find_all("tr")[0].img.get("alt")
    tds = jog.find_all("td", {"class": "zentriert"})
    posicao = tds[0].get("title")
    idade = tds[1].text
    nacionalidade = tds[2].img.get("alt")
    altura = tds[3].text[0:-2]
    pe = tds[4].text
    desde = tds[5].text
    try:
        clube_anterior = tds[6].img.get("alt")
    except AttributeError:
        clube_anterior = None
    preco_pago = tds[6].get("title")
    contrato = tds[7].text
    valor = jog.find("td", {"class": "rechts hauptlink"}).text[0:-4]
    bahia.append(
        (
            nome,
            posicao,
            idade,
            nacionalidade,
            altura,
            pe,
            desde,
            clube_anterior,
            preco_pago,
            contrato,
            valor,
        )
    )
```